# Metroframework tabcontrol icon in tabpage header

Tags: icons, tabcontrol

I would like to display an icon in the header of the metrotabpage, I've tried with imagelist but it doesn't work. So how can I do it? It works with normal tabcontrol imagelist though.

Comment: Can you share some more context?

Comment: ive tried with metrotabcontrol.imagelist = imagelist1; and on tabpage metrotabpage1.imageindex = 0; in the imagelist is one image. and im using metroframework for winforms